# Printing with a pause not working in Java

Tags: java

I have been trying to get a program writen in java to output text letter by letter with a pause in between each letter. The code word-wraps a string and prints it. My delay method "slow()" works well when the delay is half a second or a second, but at lower delay times it does some weird things.

When printing and the delay is extra short, the program hangs on that line for the delay times the number of letters being printed before the line return and then spits everything out at once.

Also when the delay is set to 250 milliseconds the text also prints out incorrectly.

In the example the string is:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae molestie leo, sed molestie turpis."

The expected output would be:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
>   elit. Nulla vitae molestie leo, sed molestie turpis.

But the output at 250 is:

> Lrem ipsum dolrst aet, conseteur adipiscing
>   elit. ulla vitae olestie lo sed oleste turis.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae molestie leo, sed molestie turpis.";
    say(500,x); // Works Nicely, does one letter at a time with a 0.5s wait in between.
    System.out.println();
    say(250,x); // Has proper delay, but prints strange stuff
    System.out.println();
    say(100,x); // Prints Line by line with a wait of (letters*0.1s) wait in between.
}

public static void say(int speed, String words) {
    int i = 0;
    int ii = 0;
    while (i < words.length()) {
        slow(speed);
        System.out.print("" + words.charAt(i));
        if (ii >= 50 && words.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            System.out.println(words.charAt(i));
            ii = 0;
        } else {
            ii++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}

public static void slow(int time) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(time);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

Alternate `slow()` method with same glitches:

```
public static void slow(int time) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < time) {

    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's important, but this is all done in NetBeans 7.4 x64 with JDK 1.7.

I am new to Java, but not new to programming. Any help would be appreciated!
The main problem is the timing, that is what I need to work; The weird printing is just a question why.

Comment: Good question, kinda long... That's some interesting behavior...

Comment: I have not tested it yet (a compilable example is always preferred), but try a `System.out.flush()` after printing out a single letter (and before waiting)

Comment: Potentially, you will print out the same charter twice at the 50 character point

Comment: Works for me just fine, with or without `flush()` call, in Eclipse.

Comment: @Marco13 Tested and it doesn't seem work, but thanks! Also for future reference, what's a compilable example?

Comment: Your code is compilable as-is.  The only thing you could have done differently is make it all one code-block so it could be copy-pasted in one go, but that's nitpicking.

Comment: It works in Eclipse, and also as a jar file invoked from the command line.  There's nothing wrong with your code, something must be wrong with your environment.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks! I downloaded Eclipse and tried it. It worked as expected! Just wondering if you know any reason why NetBeans could be acting strangely? Or do you not use it?

Comment: Doesn't work in Netbeans console, possibly because it's using a `BufferedReader` to read the Java processes output.  Works at the console though just fine.  Did change `System.out.println(words.charAt(i));` to `System.out.println();` though

Comment: Looks like problem is due to Netbeans console. I tried the code you gave in Netbeans and got the same wrong results. Later run the same code from console. And it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This smells fishy.. Your code looks good and works just fine for me, having run it from the command line.  I think, like Jim Garrison said, this has to do with your environment.  Have you tried running your program from the command line so as to leave Netbeans out of it?

The next thing I would suspect is the line `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` in your `catch(InterruptedException ex)` block.  Try commenting that out (and doing nothing except maybe printing the `InterruptedException` stack trace (`ex.printStackTrace()`).

Answer (score 0):

### Idiomatic solution using Timer/TimerTask:

#### Idiomatic things to note:

1. Use of [BreakIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) to separate the text apart.
2. Use of [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)/[TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to manage the delays.
3. Use of [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) for thread safe shared object.

#### Q23794090.java

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import java.text.BreakIterator;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Q23794090
{
    private static final Timer TIMER = new Timer();
    private static AtomicLong DELAY = new AtomicLong(0L);

    private static void say(final long delay, @Nonnull final String value, @Nonnull final BreakIterator bi)
    {
        bi.setText(value);
        int start = bi.first();
        int end = bi.next();

        while (end != BreakIterator.DONE)
        {
            final String s = value.substring(start, end);
            TIMER.schedule(new TimerTask()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    System.out.print(s);
                }
            }, DELAY.addAndGet(delay));
            start = end;
            end = bi.next();
        }
        TIMER.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("========================");
            }
        }, DELAY.addAndGet(0));
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final String x = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae molestie leo, sed molestie turpis.";
        say(250, x, BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance());
        say(500, x, BreakIterator.getWordInstance());
        say(1000, x, BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance());
        TIMER.schedule(new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                TIMER.cancel();
            }
        }, DELAY.addAndGet(1000));
        try { Thread.currentThread().join(); } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
    }
}
```

#### Works in Intellij Idea 13.x

In the console so there is no problems with having to call `System.out.flush()` any nonsense like that.

#### Things to improve:

1. `BreakIterator` factory methods take an optional `Locale`, since there isn't a `Latin` one that I could find easily, I just let it use the default. In my case this is `en_US`. Your milage may vary.